# How to properly assert runtime generated excel workbook(or binary files) in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

I'm trying to write a Spring boot test to assert an Excel workbook generated at runtime using Apache Poi library and zipped it. The zip file path is then stored at a location and the path is sent to the client response.  I'm not sure how do I properly assert it. Like what parmaters do I need to assert kind of thing. As of now I could check only the `ZipEntry` of `ZipFile` is not null.

I don't have expected file to compare and assert. And I tried below checklist.

1. MD5 hash - both programmatically checked and manually using `md5sum` linux command
2. File size - Since it is zipped, there was no noticable change in each case
3. Even tried having expected file - MD5 hash was different

```java
String generatedFilePath = "<FILE_PATH>";
try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(generatedFilePath)) {
    ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry("my_excel_file.xlsx"); // at root of the zip only
    assertNotNull(zipEntry);
}
```

Please help me on this to harden the test.

Comment: Why is MD5 not helping you? It's probably the best approach for this test because of how sensitive it is to change- if even a single byte changes, the whole output will change too.

Comment: @ShanS ya unfortunately it did not help. Everytime the test run, there was new MD5 hash generated. I checked manually peeking into the zip file. The content was not changed. But what I assumed is even the metadata like the file time created is variable. I also tried `md5Sum` linux command to manually check

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're trying to test is that the xlsx file you generate is valid, and that the zip file is valid. It's two separate tasks, so it's best to write two tests- one for the xlsx processing, and one for the zipping process. For the excel file, you could test that the generated file is what you expect it to be, by reading it again and checking the important spreadsheet features (such as the number of spreadsheets, their names, values in cells, images, and so on).

For zipping, you could test that the zip file extracts successfully. This solution isn't perfect and is a bit more work but it does meet *most* of the general requirements for writing a good unit test: that the test is modular, tests one thing at a time, that it's portable, and tests the behavior/end result, not the implementation. [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) and [Unit Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://www.manning.com/books/unit-testing) are good resources for more information.

Comment: I tried this way and I also again kept expected file and I checked the cell values. Spreadsheet is filled with price values with decimal point and some other data types like string. While reading, the precision for price values is different from expected file. 0 and 0.0

Comment: That's an issue with the library you're using- I'm not familiar with it, so you'll have to configure it to read your example properly, according to the test case.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into that